# Question about theorem with trees

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I know the theorem:

> for an undirected graph on $n$ nodes, any of the following two imply the
>   third:
>
> - $G$ is connected
> - $G$ does not contain a cycle
> - $G$ has $n-1$ edges

([source](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/pearson/03Graphs.pdf))

Would it be correct to add "graph is a tree" and have any two conditions imply all four?

> for an undirected graph, any of the following two imply the third:
>
> - $G$ is connected
> - $G$ does not contain a cycle
> - $G$ has $n-1$ edges
> - $G$ is a tree

I think this is true because, by definition, if you know it is a tree then the first two conditions are implied.

The definition of tree I am using is

> An undirected graph is a tree if it is connected and does not contain
>   a cycle

Comment: What definition of a tree are you using?

Comment: Since the fourth condition implies each of the other three, and the first three conditions imply the fourth, this does hold.

Comment: @DylanSp added to question

Answer (score 2):

With that definition of a tree, your formulation is correct, it's just not very useful; the definition includes the first two statements. The power of the initial theorem is that from *any* two of the three statements, we can conclude the third.

Comment: What other definitions of graph are there? According to wiki there are a few but they're all equivalent https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29#Definitions

Comment: @Celeritas They're all equivalent, but this question is about the distinction between equivalent statements, so the exact formulation matters.